# CSharpCodeProvider set and verify .NET profile version

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, mono, csharpcodeprovider

I'm using mono for an embedded scripting environment in my application. For the compilation of the scripts I use Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider. Now I require some 4.0 or 4.5 Functionality like System.Numerics. However, referencing the System.Numerics.dll in the compiler options just gets me the error

> (0,0) : error CS0006: Metadata file `System.Numerics.dll' could not be found

Since the assembly location of the provider points to the 2.0.0.0 gac I'm not too surprised to see this fail. However, with mono-2.11.4 and the v4.0 and v4.5 profiles in place I wonder why the provider does not find the required assemblies or if it even provides v4.0 as requested.

```
var provider_options = new Dictionary<string,string>();
provider_options.Add("CompilerVersion", "v4.0");
CodeDomProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(provider_options);
CompilerParameters cparams = new CompilerParameters ();
cparams.GenerateExecutable = true;
cparams.OutputAssembly = Path.ChangeExtension(rFileNames[0],".exe");
cparams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add( "System.dll" );
cparams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add( "System.Windows.Forms.dll" );
cparams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add( "System.Drawing.dll" );
cparams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add( "Mono.Debugger.Soft.dll" ); 
cparams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add( "System.Numerics.dll" );
```

Comment: You're requesting the *compiler* version 4.0 - that's somewhat independent of the *framework* you're using. What version of the framework are you compiling and running *this* code against?

Comment: I do compile using dmcs with option -sdk:4

Comment: Sorry, I'm stupid. Now finally after spending a few days head-scratching and trying I noticed that I just have to enforce the v4.0 engine for the mono jit ( mDomain = mono_jit_init_version ("Root Domain","v4.0");) ... facepalm.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following Jon's comment I was thinking about the executing framework. Although the page [embedding mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono) states that `mono_jit_init (domain_name);`

> "... will return a MonoDomain where your code will be executed. domain_name is the name of the main application domain. This call will initialize the default framework version, which could be 2.0 or 4.0, depending on the Mono version used."

It does not return a .net 4.0 domain for mono 2.11.4, although I was tempted to believe this. 
Enforcing the version by calling `mono_jit_init_version ("myapp", ""v4.0);` works fine.